# When is $I - ACA$ nonsingular with $A$ being symmetric and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the matrix $I - ACA$ with $A$ being symmetric positive definite and $C$ being symmetric. I want to ensure that $I - ACA$ is nonsingular. What condition (on $C$) do I need? I found the Woodburry formula but it seems like this makes things rather complicated (and since I don't need the inverse but just the conditions to ensure the matrix can be inverted).

Comment: In the title you say that $A$ is *symmetric* and positive definite; in the question, you only say that it's positive definite, but that $C$ is symmetric. So....can you please reconcile these? (You can click "edit" below your question to change things, including the title).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I edited it. Meant was $A$ being a SPD matrix.

Comment: If the matrix is singular, we have $I=ACA$, so $A^{-1}=CA=AC$. However I'm not quite sure if it's sufficient to make $AC\neq CA$

Comment: @Divide1918 The matrix being singular does not necessarily mean that $I - ACA = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh wait you're right... I got confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful: by the Woodbury identity, your matrix $M = I - ACA$ is invertible whenever $C$ is non-singular and $C^{-1} - A^2$ is non-singular.

In fact, we can make a stronger statement: given that $C$ is non-singular, $M$ will be invertible if and only if $C^{-1} - A^2$ is non-singular. In particular, the formula implies that if $M$ is non-singular, then $A^{-1}(M - I)A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $C^{-1}- A^2$.

Comment: @user8675309 Good catch, I think I've fixed the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

here's another sufficient condition:

an easier problem is considering $\det\big(I-C\big)\neq 0$, which is testing whether $C$ has an eigenvalue of 1.

This is easily true when $ \mathbf 0\succeq C$, i.e. when $C$ is symmetric negative semi-definite.  Note this explicitly allows $\det\big(C\big) =0$.  Now  $A^TCA = ACA$ for SPD $A$ is a congruence transform and by Sylvester's Law of Inertia, negative semidefinite $A^TCA$ still has all non-positive eigenvalues, so $\det\big(I-A^TCA\big)\neq 0$.

In short, another sufficient condition: negative semidefinite $C$, which allows $C$ to be singular.